# Filtering from IgniteRDD happen locally in Spark Application or in Ignite Server?

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

If I execute a Filter on IgniteRDD, then the filter is pushed-down to Ignite Server, or first the Spark RDD should first collect all the data and then execute the filter within Spark Application?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `collect` at all, but as far as I know there is a distinction between to cases:

- Plain `filter` will use standard Spark execution.
- `sql` will be processed by Ignite itself without Spark usage.

Answer (score -2):

It all depends on Catalyst Optimizer. You can check the plans to understand your pipeline and see where is it executed. Also debugging might help.

As it explains [here](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v1.9.0/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd#igniterdd) - IgniteRDD is an implementation of Spark RDD to represent Ignite cache and use spark API. As example there shows - filter would operate on cache directly.

Comment: RDD -> no Catalyst. Catalyst belongs to Dataset API.